# Transparency shader help

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I've added a backface culling material shader to the sphere, and I wanna remove parts of the monkey mesh that resides inside the sphere.

I'm very close, but for some reason after I rotate my view 90 degrees to see the other side of the monkey, the parts that were transparent suddenly greys out.

[image]

Comment: In Eevee you can't see an object with Screen Space Refraction through another one, maybe it's your problem here? In that case you need to find a trick